# Exporting and Importing to Unity

Tags: export, texture-baking, unity

I used the texture brush to apply 2 textures to my first ever 3D model in Blender, and exported it as .FBX into my Unity assets folder, but once I drag-and-drop it into my scene it doesnt have any textures at all?

I have also tried just saving the .blend file, but that does the same thing!

Im posting this in both forums because im not sure if it's an issue with Blender exporting, or an issue with Unity importing.

Do I have to bake the textures onto the model before exporting? if so can someone give me a step-by-step?

Does anyone have any idea where it's going wrong?

[image: Blender]

[image: Render Result]

[image: Unity]

Comment: Using Blender 2.8, tried to do it using cycles rendering, 1 Material used with 2 textures painted on it.

Comment: SOLVED. No tutorial I have ever watched has said "dont forget to save your UV map seperately so you can add it to your 3D model in Unity", brand new users will expect that when they Bake a material onto the model, the textures will also be baked, this is far too simple a concept for Blender to do it seems.